# How to return the request body back to client after executing API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a simple API-Gateway client and all I want to do is include the request body, initially sent by client when hitting the api, back to the client. This is just to confirm that the api received the expected request body.

I tried using the following mapping templates, but they return empty:

```
{
  "requestBody": $method.request.body // also tried this with the quotes around the value
}
```

```
{
  "requestBody": "integration.request.body"
}
```

This is an SQS integration, however, I just want the request body sent to the api itself independent of what sqs received.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your Integration Response mapping template should do the trick:

```
{
    "body-json" : $input.json('$')
}
```

Also, if you want to see even more, look for the **Generate template** dropdown just above the mapping template and select **Method Request passthrough** to generate a mapping template that returns all passed in data (body, query strings, etc) back to the client.